# How to build/mantain an affinity score between 2 users?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database-design, affinity

I mean analyzing 2 users profiles I get a score that it is reciprocal
`a.affinity(b) == b.affinity(a)`

I'd like to know in particular:

- which schema would u use to implement the affinity table
- which db mysql, redis,..
- which technology would you use to update the affinity score in background?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For the db design part, I would recommend using the [join/junction table concept](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table), except in this case you're joining a table to itself. For example, if your user table looks something like:

```
UserId   UserName
------   --------
1        User Uno
2        User Dos
...
```

Then your join table would look something like:

```
UserIdA  UserIdB    AffinityScore
------   --------   -------------
1        2          56
34       208        137
```

where UserIdA and UserIdB are foreign keys to UserId in the first table. (You'd have to check and make sure that once UidA and UidB are set, e.g. values 1 and 2 respectively, that the relationship is not repeated if the values are swapped, e.g. values 2 and 1 respectively for UidA and UidB which could cause some weirdness in the app. You could use the CHECK constraint if using [Sql Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179491.aspx) or [MySql](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_check.asp).)

As far the join table concept goes, your choice of db does not matter. It's just a table with foreign keys. And for doing background updates, it depends on your platform. Could be a cron job initiating an executable or SSIS (Sql Server) running T-Sql script and many things in between.

Comment: > You'd have to check and make sure that once UidA and UidB are set...
You got the point, is possible to force that IdA < IdB at the db level or it can be done only at higher level?

Comment: Ah, interesting. It really depends on the db engine you're using and types of constraints/checks that are allowed. I do like the IdA > IdB (or vice versa) solution. Simple and elegant. Sql Server would allow that, see here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179491.aspx and actually MySql has something similar: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_check.asp (Will fold this comment into my answer too.)